# Javascript to slide a div off the left of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there are various solutions out there, including JQuery solutions, that will do this, but I was trying to write my own simple version...

I want to hide a `<div>` but sliding it off the left or right of the screen.

For some reason I'm unable to read and set the `.style.left` value of my `div` though.

This fiddle shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/47MNX/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to work fine if you set the position property, e.g. `position:absolute;` (or relative) to `#myLeftMenu`. You never set the position, so while the JavaScript was running it had no way to make the change.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/47MNX/4/)**

Comment: Ah, silly error. I'll post the full function once it's complete in case anyone wants to re-use.

Comment: This has got me a long way, however I don't understand why I can't read the `.style.left` value from the `<div>` when I enter the function (or anywhere else I've tried for that matter). If you uncomment the second `alert` in the move function you'll see what I mean. I want to read this to inform some toggle functionality.

Comment: After some more experimentation, it seems that the `style.left` property is only availble to read if it has been hard coded in the `<div>` tag rather than when it is in the css. Is this correct?

Comment: No, that's not correct. And to answer the previous question, when setting styles via a stylesheet, you need to read them via getComputedStyle (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle)

Comment: By the way, you really shouldn't unaccept a question when the answer still holds. Your question about reading non-inline styles is secondary to your original question. In fact, it could be a separate question since it's not directly related to the problem above.

Comment: My completed solution (including a toggle function) can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/47MNX/15/ . It uses no JQuery or external libraries and is just simple JavaScript. Thanks to @j08691 for all the help on this. (And sorry, I didn't realise I'd  unaccepted the answer, must have been a mis-click when looking at your fiddle. Have accepted again.)

Comment: Oops, I'd left some old code in that fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/47MNX/16/ has the corrected code.